# ProcessObject loses connection to StandardOuput

Tags: external-calls, asynchronous-processing

At many points I've wanted to connect to an external process, have it run, and communicate with it via stdin and stdout interactively. At many points I have been stymied.

With the `$SystemShell` it works:

```
In[205]:= 
$shell = 
 StartProcess[$SystemShell]; WriteLine[$shell, "echo \"O God why hast thou forsaken me\""];
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;

Out[206]= ""

Out[207]= "O God why hast thou forsaken me"
```

All good.

With something that should be generating an interactive dialog, like the program `spcat` which has a file-input dialog:

```
In[315]:= 
$shell = StartProcess[$spcat];
WriteLine[$spcat, "~/Desktop/lampe_dt.spe"]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;

Out[317]= ""

Out[318]= ""
```

Nothing.

Moreover I've tossed in a dialog there that ought to be opening a window. Still zilch.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I honestly can't figure out what's different between these.

And lest anyone think the issue is that my system doesn't recognize `$spcat`:

```
In[306]:= 
$shell = StartProcess[{$spcat, "~/Desktop/lampe_dt.spe"}];
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;

Out[307]= ""

Out[308]= "~/Desktop/lampe_dt.int
~/Desktop/lampe_dt.var
~/Desktop/lampe_dt.out
~/Desktop/lampe_dt.cat
~/Desktop/lampe_dt.str
~/Desktop/lampe_dt.egy
 Trouble opening ~/Desktop/lampe_dt.out
"
```

One other thing to note, I can't get `python` to work with `StartProcess` at all:

```
In[320]:= 
$shell = StartProcess[{"python", "-c", "print(';_;')"}];
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;

Out[321]= ""

Out[322]= ""
```

Although it works fine with `RunProcess`:

```
In[324]:= RunProcess[{"python", "-c", "print(';_;')"}]

Out[324]= <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> ";_;
  ", "StandardError" -> ""|>
```

If someone more knowledgable than I could take pity on my poor soul that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you need to take into account that the subprocess you start needs some time until it is ready to write. So in many cases just waiting a bit will solve your issue, e.g. the following will work:

```
$shell = StartProcess[{"C:\\Python27\\python.exe", "-c","print(';_;')"}];
Pause[0.5];
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;
```

But the real purpose of using `StartProcess` compared to `RunProcess` is that you want to interact with the program by feeding its standard input and reading its standard output. The problem with that is that many programs behave differently depending on whether or not they think they are connected to a terminal or not. In many cases when they are not connected to a terminal they will immediately exit when they are done or handle the standard input/output channels differently.

It is easiest to demonstrate for your example using python. If calling `python --help` on the commandline you will see among other information something like:

```
...
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
...
```

so one step to make the python subprocess work more like you want is to start it with the `-i` option: it then will not exit but stay alive and wait for your input (note that you still need to give it some time to start):

```
$shell = StartProcess[{"python", "-i"}]
WriteLine[$shell, "print(\"O God why hast thou forsaken me\")"];
Pause[0.5];
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardError"], EndOfBuffer]
ReadString[ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"], EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@$shell;
```

Now whether or not this will work still depends on things and timings that might be different on different machines. This is of course a bit error prone, as the time you would need to wait could depend on the load on your machine. It might actually be better to do something like this:

```
output = ""; count = 0;
$shell = StartProcess[{"python", "-i", "-c","print(';_;')"}];
While[StringMatchQ[output, ""] && count++ < 1000,
 output = ReadString[
    ProcessConnection[$shell, "StandardOutput"],EndOfBuffer];
 Pause[0.01];
];
output
```

As you can see it can be a bit complicated to reliably communicate between two interacting processes.

As for your actual problem I see two ways to solve it: try whether waiting a bit before reading (and writing) to the subprocess and see whether that helps. If not, consult the documentation of `spcat` to see whether it has some option like the `-i` of python. If that is not the case, you would need to start it in a way so that it believes it is connected to a terminal. The details of how to achieve that are OS dependent and out of scope of this site and my memory. You probably should ask that at a different site. If you want to search for more information, some terms to search for are terminals, pseudo-terminals and coprocesses ...

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. It's interesting that `python` (at least on Mac) truly does need the `i`, because in the past I wrote a mainloop simulator to keep the process alive and that still wouldn't connect to stdin / out. Also interesting is that `StartProcess` doesn't wait for the process to initialized. I had assumed it was more like `RunProcess` in that way, rather than, say `subprocess.call` in python. Many thanks for this. I can finally build my Mathematica python shell :) Who knows what `spcat` does. It isn't the most professionally developed program.